# Error while installing Oracle 11g on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g

I am trying to install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu 14.04 using the command `./runInstaller -silent` but I am getting this error:

```
Checking temp space: 1 MB available, 120 MB required.    Failed
```

I tried doing the below but the error persisted:

> - change to root
>
> su – root
>
> - make new folder for the temporary files
>
> mkdir /u01/tmp
>
> - change the owner which you will use to install the product, in my case
>     user is oracle and the group oinstall.
>
> chown oracle:oinstall /u01/tmp
>
> - change the read-write settings
>
> chmod 1777 /u01/tmp
>
> - export the new path so that the installer can use it
>
> export TEMP=/u01/tmp
>   export TMPDIR=/u01/tmp

Comment: Is this the whold command `./runInstaller -silent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#CEGEGDBA) says to export environment variables `TMP` and `TMPDIR`, not `TEMP`:

> If you determined that the /tmp directory has less than 1 GB of free
>   disk space, then identify a file system with at least 1 GB of free
>   space and set the `TMP` and `TMPDIR` environment variables to specify a
>   temporary directory on this file system:
>
> To determine the free disk space on each mounted file system use the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> # df -h /tmp
> ```
>
> If necessary, enter commands similar to the following to create a
>   temporary directory on the file system that you identified, and set
>   the appropriate permissions on the directory:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mkdir /mount_point/tmp
> $ sudo chmod a+wr /mount_point/tmp
> # exit
> ```
>
> Enter commands similar to the following to set the `TMP` and `TMPDIR`
>   environment variables:
>
> - Bourne, Bash, or Korn shell:
>
>   ```
>   $ TMP=/mount_point/tmp
>   $ TMPDIR=/mount_point/tmp
>   $ export TMP TMPDIR
>   ```
> - C shell:
>
>   ```
>   % setenv TMP /mount_point/tmp
>   % setenv TMPDIR /mount_point/tmp
>   ```

The [blog you quoted from](http://web-center-suite.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/fix-not-enough-temp-space-when-try-to.html) seems to be wrong, though that is for "Oracle Web Tier" not the database software anyway. It also doesn't make it clear that you need to do the `export` commands as your Oracle user, not as root, in the shell you'll run the installer from.

Comment: the systemis asking for 120 MB, where should I specify this?

Comment: @AliIssa - not sure I understand what you mean; whatever directory you create and set `TMP` and `TMPDIR` too, has to have that much free space - which you can check with `df -h $TMP`. You don't set that explicitly anywhere, unless you're creating a new filesystem. (You really only have 1MB free in /tmp!?).